# Invert colors setting of mobile affecting colors in expo app . like white turn to black and so on

Tags: react-native, expo

Invert colors setting of mobile  affecting colors in expo app . like white turn to black and so on . Please guide me over this. How can disable it

Comment: try setting "userInterfaceStyle" to "light" in app.json

Comment: yes used it but  did not work

Comment: are you building a standalone application? or are you using Expo Go? In Expo Go, this setting is set to "automatic"